# Installing OpenCV Python Bindings on Mac with VirtualEnv: Can't find interpreter

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, cmake

I've been following [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) guide on installing OpenCV on MacOS.  I'm stuck on step 8, where you cmake everything.

From the `~/opencv/build` directory, I run

```
$ cmake 
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
    -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
    -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin 
    -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF 
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON 
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON 
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

If I run the cmake command from outside the venv, it fails to find the interpreter/numpy version in the virtualenv:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin (ver 2.7.12)
--     numpy:                       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
--     packages path:               /Users/peter/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If I run from inside the venv:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /Users/peter/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
```

It find the correct interpreter but won't find the numpy path.

Can I have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 1):

Well, eventually I went with the following approach: Don't bother getting cmake to use the virtualenv interpreter.  You can just compile opencv and the copy the cv2.so file into your virtualenv.  In my case this involved proceeding with the [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/), then using the command

```
cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so ~/projects/spiking-experiments/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

To copy the file.  Now I can import cv2 from inside the virtualenv.